# How to create Array of Dictionaries from comma separated strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am receiving comma separated string as below which is to be converted to array of dictionaries.I tried using `[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];` which however gives a totally different output.What is the correct way of converting it?

```
  NSString *cancellationStr ==> [{"cutoffTime":"0-2","refundInPercentage":"0"},{"cutoffTime":"2-3","refundInPercentage":"50"},{"cutoffTime":"3-24","refundInPercentage":"90"}]

 NSArray *array = [cancellationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 

  //Gives response like below

(
"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"0-2\"",
"\"refundInPercentage\":\"0\"}",
"{\"cutoffTime\":\"2-3\"",
"\"refundInPercentage\":\"50\"}",
"{\"cutoffTime\":\"3-24\"",
"\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
)
```

The code to fetch and parse using a singleton HTTP class

```
   NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@sourceCity=%@&destinationCity=%@&doj=%@",BASE_URL,AVAILABLE_BUSES,source,destination,dateStr];
   urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    SuccessBlock successBlock = ^(NSData *responseData){
    NSError *error;
    jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
     bArray = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"apiAvailableBuses"];
      };

     FailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error){
     NSLog(@"%@",error);
     };


HTTPRequest *request = [[HTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:url successBlock:successBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
[request startRequest];
```

The above success block receives the string which then I am looking to convert.

```
    NSString *cancellationStr = [[bArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex]valueForKey:@"cancellationPolicy"];

    bObject.cancellationPolicy = [cancellationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"Cancellation Array : %@",bObject.cancellationPolicy);
```

Comment: Parse the JSON with NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: done that...this is the received response BTW

Comment: Show your code where you process `myString` using `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: I'm guessing he did DataWithObject instead of ObjectWithData.

Comment: Show us the JSON you fed into NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: Show us the original JSON!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, "apiAvailableBusses" is an array of elements like this one:

```
{
    "operatorId":196,
    "operatorName":"Sahara Bus",
    "departureTime":"6:45 PM",
    "mTicketAllowed":false,
    "idProofRequired":false,
    "serviceId":"1602",
    "fare":"450",
    "busType":"Sahara Hitech Non A/c",
    "routeScheduleId":"1602",
    "availableSeats":29,
    "partialCancellationAllowed":false,
    "arrivalTime":"07:30 AM",
    "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"12\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"0\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"24\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"50\"}]",
    "commPCT":0.0,
    "boardingPoints":[
        {
            "time":"09:05PM",
            "location":"Ameerpet,Kaveri Kmakshi Travels,Beside RKS Mall,Ameerpet, Mr.Aman-9391830030.",
            "id":"6"
        },
        {
            "time":"09:15PM",
            "location":"Punjagutta,Sai Ganesh Travels, Punjagutta, Mr.Aman-9391830030.",
            "id":"2241"
        },
        {
            "time":"09:30PM",
            "location":"Lakdi-ka-pool,Sahara Travels,Hotel Sri Krishna Complex,Mr.Aman-9391830030.",
            "id":"2242"
        },
        {
            "time":"08:45PM",
            "location":"ESI,Behind Bajaj Show Room, Near Nani Travels. Mr.Aman-9391830030.",
            "id":"2287"
        },
        {
            "time":"09:45PM",
            "location":"Nampally,Near Khaja Travels, Nampally,Mr.Aman-9391830030.",
            "id":"2321"
        },
        {
            "time":"09:16PM",
            "location":"Paradise,Near SVR Travels, Paradise,Mr.Aman-9391830030.",
            "id":"2322"
        },
        {
            "time":"10:00PM",
            "location":"Afzalgunj,Sahar Travels,Mr.Aman-9391830030.",
            "id":"2323"
        },
        {
            "time":"09:00PM",
            "location":"Secunderbad Station,Near Asian Travels.Mr.Aman-9391830030.",
            "id":"2336"
        }
    ],
    "droppingPoints":null,
    "inventoryType":0
}
```

The "cancellationPolicy" element is a string which is what is called "embedded JSON".  (Why they did that in this case I haven't a clue.)  This means that the string must be fed through NSJSONSerialization *again*.  And to convert the NSString to NSData (to feed through NSJSONSerialization again) you need to first use `dataWithEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`.